# How to get access to particular array of object by clicking button

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have two image buttons and my JSON response is an array of objects and I want to access both objects one by one by clicking. By doing this I am getting only the second position but i want while clicking first button i want first object and for second button i want second object.

While parsing data I am getting only the second position, light type object only.

```
final String potentialId = SitesUtil.getInstance().getSelectedPotentialId();

String urlOne = UrlUtility.getActionUrl(potentialId, cameraId);
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlOne, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ActionButton[] actionButton = gson.fromJson(response, ActionButton[].class);
        for (ActionButton actionButton1 : actionButton) {
            getOnUrl = actionButton1.getOnUrl();
            getOffUrl = actionButton1.getOffUrl();
            getType = actionButton1.getType();
            message = actionButton1.getOnSuccessMessage();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

**The get reponse code:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton:
            if (getType.equals("Strobe")) {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getOnUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            if (getType.equals("Light")) {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getOnUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**My JSON Response:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 28248,
        "cameraId": 19316,
        "onUrl": "",
        "offUrl": "",
        "statusUrl": "",
        "type": "Strobe",
        "statusOnMessage": "P6 = on",
        "statusOffMessage": "P6 = off",
        "onSuccessMessage": "P6 = on",
        "offSuccessMessage": "P6 = off"
    },
    {
        "id": 28844,
        "cameraId": 19316,
        "onUrl": "",
        "offUrl": "",
        "statusUrl": "",
        "type": "Light",
        "statusOnMessage": "P2 = on",
        "statusOffMessage": "P2 = off",
        "onSuccessMessage": "P2 = on",
        "offSuccessMessage": "P2 = off"
    }
]
```

Comment: pls elaborate what u need

Comment: i have two button i just want that when i pressed first one using light type then its light type URL should execute and when am press light button light url should execute but when i am doing thing its always took second position.

Comment: @hatched how to get array type  while click button?

Comment: can you explain your problem clearly?

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig i just want to excecute url in array of object i have two button  on first button i want Strobe type and for second button i want Light Url execution.

Comment: first button should took first position but while excreting code its getting always second position .

Comment: Suppose if i am pressed strobe button then first object should execute but its take second .

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig any Suggestion

Comment: can any budy give me suggestion.

Comment: can any buddy give me any hint how to do that for first object and for second button.

Comment: you should clearly elaborate your question